# Are synonyms always bidirectional?

Tags: synonyms

By bidirectional I mean, if word A is synonymous with word B, does it follow that word B is always synonymous with word A? Are there any common exceptions to this rule?

Extending this - if word A is synonymous with word B, and word B is synonymous with word C, word C may or may not be synonymous with word A?

Comment: Synonyms only exist in context. So "always synonymous" makes no sense. And your extension, again, is possible for some words in some contexts, but not for other words in other contexts.

Comment: So I guess, as with most things - sweeping generalizations are always wrong!

Comment: Pretty much if one word appears on synonyms list of another, the other will appear on the list of the first. But depending on the word, word A may be always a synonym of word B, while B is a synonym of A only in specific contexts.

Comment: To extend @RegDwighт's comment, yes, -in- a given context, the relation is bidirectional. But it allows one to pursue faulty arguments by switching contexts implicitly. A pole is a post, but a post is a letter, therefore people from Poland are sealed in envelopes.

Comment: Synonyms exist in context. But in the context in which they are synonyms, the relationship is symmetric.  In a broadened context, or a different context, it might not be (so they are not synonyms).

Comment: @Mitch  The `pole -> post -> letter` problem is about transitivity, not symmetry. A relation can be symmetric, without being transitive. That is to say, it can be a rule that if A is a synonym of B, then B is a synonym of A. But that doesn't mean it has to be a rule that if A is a synonym of B, and B is a synonym of C, then A is a synonym of C. (But since synonymity is a kind of equivalence, it probably makes sense for it to be symmetric and transitive. Even reflexive: let A by a synonym of A.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perfect synonyms are equivalent, which means that all you say in your answer is true for them. But perfect synonyms are really unusual; some people say they don't exist at all.

In reality, synonyms are usually just partial, which means that they share a common meaning in some circumstances, but not in all of them. So the symmetric property (if A is a synonym of B, B is a synonym of A) holds true, but not the transitive (if A is a synonym of B and B is a synonym of C, A is a synonym of C).

Example: *lead* is a synonym of *main* (*lead actor* = *main actor*), *graphite* (in a pencil) or *conductor* (in electricity), but these words are not synonyms between them at all.

Comment: Perfect synonyms only exist when they are related to death: dead, deceased, dead body, corpse. In Spanish and French is the same thing.

Comment: @k-dev I don't think those are perfect synonyms. Further, I think there are perfect synonyms unrelated to death (e.g. *sofa* and *couch*).

Comment: @k-dev "My computer just died." is perfectly valid in English, but it doesn't leave a corpse, nor is it deceased.

Comment: Perfect synonyms applies to all cases describing an absolute condition. You either are x or not x. Extending your example: Words related to being pregnant/expecting/gestating/knocked-up.

Comment: @Zano Ideas can gestate as well, but they can't be knocked-up as far as I know..  ;)

Comment: @Izkata: Maybe they should ;-)

Comment: I don't think the example is a good one, as it exploits the fact that "lead" can have completely unrelated meanings. Sticking to the first meaning, you can indeed say "lead actor = main actor", but I don't think you can say "lead course" (in a meal), "lead entrance" (in a building) etc. whereas "main" would be perfectly ok in those cases.

Comment: @UncleZeiv: I intentionally used this example because I think it is clearer. In any case, the conclusion is the same: synonyms do not generally form clusters.

Answer (score 6):

Part of the difficulty is what we mean by *synonym*.  When we use reference works to search for synonyms, we are usually presented with a variety of choices. The Collins Thesaurus (found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88199/are-synonyms-always-bidirectional)) lists the following synonyms for the word *pistol*

> - handgun
> - shooter
> - piece (U.S. & Canad. informal)
> - automatic
> - revolver
> - side arm

Not all pistols are *revolvers*. Not all *pistols* are *automatics*. *Revolvers* are not *automatics*.

Very often a term that is either a subset or a superset of another term is considered a synonym in many contexts. One could argue that such offerings are not true synonyms, but in practice we may not make that distinction.

The very fact that we seek synonyms to words indicates that there are subtle differences between the word we know and the word we seek. If not, we would always use the original (except perhaps to avoid boredom or for euphony).

For *beauty*, the following are [listed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/beauty)

> *attractiveness, appeal, charm, grace, bloom, glamour, fairness, elegance, symmetry (formal or literary), allure, loveliness, prettiness, seductiveness, gorgeousness, pleasantness, handsomeness, pulchritude, winsomeness, comeliness, exquisiteness, seemliness, pleasingness, prepossessingness*

Some of these terms do seem to be true synonyms, but create different impressions or may be used in different contexts.  Words that are listed as synonyms often have connotations that better suit a given context. While their denotation may be roughly equivalent or even identical, their shades of meaning are not.

Answer (score 1):

Synonyms are words that sometimes have the same meaning, so they overlap. Even if A sometimes = B and B sometimes = C, that doesn't mean that A sometimes = C. See the 3-circle Venn diagram [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=venn+diagram&num=100&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=_3aKULmcIKSciAerxoH4Cw&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=995).

Answer (score 1):

You can think of two words like of tho sets of possible meaning (including denotation, connotation, contextual peculiarities, etc., etc.)

Thus, speaking of word comparison, we actually are speaking about set relations. Above-mentioned [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) are nice visualisation of how actually sets can overlap.

So, no, not all synonyms are "bidirectional" - in mathematics this called bijective, or one-to-one [correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).