# One single word for honour killing

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

honour killing is a word that carries sentiments. But its Google synonym don't. Like  assassination - is a more of a war machine word.
butchery - is not right either.

Do we have a single word for honour killing?

Comment: 'Honor killing' is probably sufficient to get the idea across. Do you absolutely need a single word? What are your real constraints?

Comment: All there is that you can come up with are phrases, and if it is a single word, such as execution, quietus and euthanasia, it just won't fit the requirements stated. Please delineate. Expand a bit more on the grounds of incident in that whether it is a soldier killed in action or a guy ordered to be executed. Honor killing is generally used for soldiers in battlefield. Are you referring to the same?

Comment: @vickyace To me, "honour killing" means something very different to that. In the UK at least, it's been used in the media a lot in recent years, to refer to things like families killing their unmarried daughters because they got pregnant. See the wiki page Pam links to in the comments to HighPerformance's answer.

Comment: @vaibhav So, please explain what you mean by "honour killing". Is it what's described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_killing ?

Comment: ***Murder*** is the usual and legal term. Only uncivilized people practice, or refer to, "honor killing".

Comment: @JohnLawler I agree wholeheartedly with that sentiment but "honour killing" does mean something more specific than "murder". Seems to me that it can't be long till we have an alternative term for it that doesn't have the positive connotation (or a negative one, like how "female genital mutilation" is replacing "female circumcision"). In the meantime I also prefer to call it "murder". Perhaps one could say "familial shame murder" or something like that to identify the particular type.

Comment: @JohnLawler Odd that an answer that said the same thing you've written has disappeared and it doesn't look like the author deleted it.

Comment: @Frank The comments included someone (I think) mistakenly thinking "honour killing"  was to do with soldiers in battle. Shame that that's gone, because it was a nice example of why people might not like to use the phrase.

Comment: @Rupe, no that is still here in the question comments. The user that answered `it's a euphemism for murder` doesn't appear to be the person that deleted the answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right! There were a few comments too but I got confused about what was where. So who else can delete it?

Comment: It's not the "meaning" of the phrase that's objectionable. It's murder for a specific cultural reason. In civilized states, the government has a monopoly on murder, and that's called "execution" or "war". Private murders are not allowed, and if someone murders another person for political reasons, they will not be prosecuted for "assassination" but for murder. In uncivilized countries, or countries at war, private murder is allowed by default, unless the victim's allies can revenge it. Children murdered by parents or relatives have no allies, so no one cares.

Comment: @JohnLawler That was my point on the now deleted answer, I don't believe there are any countries where 'honour killings' are legal (even if they may be excused, forgiven, ignored, not prosecuted, whatever). Which means murder/homicide is a synonym.

Comment: What is and is-not civilized is very much a cultural convention. As an adjective, civilized variously means: polite, orderly, reasonable, pleasant or following a rule of law. Honor Killings, mostly in the forms of armed, fatal duels, have been considered civilized and uncivilized by many societies at various points in their past, including the United States and England. Modern society may equate nonviolence with enlightenment, but history is littered with corpses of people who were killed for thinking otherwise.

Comment: Of course. One can easily be murdered for defying traditions. The point is whether one should use a phrase that intimates that murdering children can be justified by "honour". There is no honor, with or without a silent U, in murdering children. Period.

Comment: Also, @JohnLawler murder specifically refers to an unlawful killing. The phrase "The government has a monopoly on murder" is an oxymoron. Even if execution and military lethality were outlawed by the US Government tomorrow, killing condoned or carried out by the government *in the past* would not become murders due to *ex post facto* laws themselves being outlawed by clause 3 of Article I, Section 9 of the United States Constitution.

Comment: That is, of course, what the state has to call it, because by their definition, what they do is not murder. But it's murder, anyway.

Comment: @Frank I don't see how one can say that "murder" is a *synonym* for "honour killing". Many murders are not honour killings.

Comment: @Rupe All honour killings are murders, not all murders are honour killings. Murder is a synonym for honour killing, honour killing is NOT a synonym for murder. Maybe that's not quite clear in my earlier comment (but it is what I meant)

Comment: Ok I think I see what you're saying. I'm more used to *synonym* being used for closer meanings. The way I'd put it is that if they want a *single word* for it then that may be the closest superset, which I think may be a similar sentiment.

Comment: @Rupe I was about to ask a question is synonyms were symmetric when EL&U suggested [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88199/are-synonyms-always-bidirectional) as a duplicate. You may find it interesting; it explains that there are *perfect* and *partial* synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

There is a neologism mentioned in the media: ***honoricide***.

> Maclean's outdid the rest of the media when it called the four murders “honoricide.” While the word “honoricide” literally means “killing of honour” but were getting at the idea of “killing for honour.” Writer Michael Friscolanti sat throughout the three-month trial and wrote a 22-page comprehensive article detailing the girls’ lives and even wrote about how one of the girls’ tombstones has the incorrect birthdate.
>
> <sub>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Arianawardak/sandbox</sub>

Comment: For me, this neologism doesn't really deal with the issue.

Comment: @Rupe: What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a decent answer to the question. It's just that the problems people have with the phrase "honour killing" are connected with the "honour" part of it, and that's still there.

Comment: @Rupe: That is related with an opinion based discussion. I'm just giving an objective answer.

Comment: Sure, and I've voted you up for that. But the OP mentioned the "sentiments" associated with the various words offered, so I thought it appropriate to also comment on how any alternative might fit in to that way of looking at things.

Answer (score 3):

As the flood of comments has probably made clear, this is a controversial subject. Wikipedia has a [list of types of killing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_killing) that is ... extensive. It includes [Honor-Killing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor-killing) under the heading of **Killing of family**. This came as a surprise to me, as I would have classified Honor-Killing as killing of others due to reasons of personal honor having been offended, as in the history of [duels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel). This is supported by the meanings of the phrases *honorable combat*, *trial by combat* and *field of honor*.

I was incorrect.

Honor-killing instead has a historical meaning of a killing of a family member who has brought shame to their family.

You might note that most of the types of killing are characterized by who or what is being killed and the specific relationship between the perpetrator and victim. Some examples:

- Homicide: from Latin *homo* for human being and *caedere*. Killing of one human by another.
- Regicide: Latin *rex* for king. The assassination of a Monarch by their subjects.
- Fratricide: killing of a brother.

In fact, there are only seven terms from among 60+ that don't use the suffix *-cide*. Not counting the two subtypes of suicide, these terms are:

- Honor-killing
- Murder
- Manslaughter
- Capital Punishment (a.k.a. execution)
- Euthanasia

<sub>Disclaimer: I know this is not a complete nor definitive list of words relating to killing. I am only building an argument on the ratio of terms presented, which I believe this list is large enough to indicate a definitive trend in the English language.</sub>

There are 58 well-documented terms (and several more less-than-documented terms) in this list with the *-cide* suffix which describe the victim of the killing. In this framework, honor-killing as a term meaning "killing for honor" is an oxymoron. A definition that would match the parts of the phrase at hand would be "the killing of honor." Ermanem points out the neologism of honoricide, which even more strongly opposes the pattern. I would like to counter this with a neologism of my own.

What an honor-kiling attempts to accomplish is the abatement of shame the perpetrator is feeling over the actions of a family member. I propose a better term for this is **Shame-Killing** or <sub>for a Latin fetishist phrase</sub> pudicide.

As John Lawler points out, Honor-killing often takes the form of a parent killing a child for disobeying them, and not even in a life threatening or even dangerous way. If the child is underage (as is frequently the case when judged by modern, western standards), then this is a failing of the parent to protect and care for their child. If the child *is* of age and expected to act as an individual and an adult, then there can be no dispute that this is a **murder**. There cannot exist such a high-stakes state where an individual is responsible for their own actions and answerable to a legal guardian, especially not with their life. Most democratic forms of governance hold that citizens are answerable only to the state. Even state-sponsored killing do not attempt to trivialize the death with a sugar-coated term – as already mentioned, this is called an execution, capital punishment or death penalty. The stated goal of such killings is not to restore the honor of the society, but to remove an ongoing danger to society.

Also note that sometimes Honor-killings are undertaken when the victim has no responsibility for the perceived offense, having already been victimized by another perpetrator. In this case, the victim who is killed is innocent of all wrong doing – one could even call them a martyr.

In either case, I view these types of killings as an ultimate admission of failure by the perpetrator, who views their own situation as so bleak and unrecoverable that they must attempt to erase the source of their shame, as though ending a life could change the past. Even the phrasing "honor-killing" is an attempt to put a positive light on a violent act. This fits the definition of propaganda, as evidenced by how contrary it is to other phrases regarding killings.

Comment: +1 For discussion and *Shame-killing*, that's a nice simple way of reversing the positivity.

Comment: Referencing *pudor* is reasonable, but I can never tell whether something like *pudicide* means killing the shame or the shamer. The phonetic proximity of *pudor* to words like *puta* and *pudenda* might make *pudicide* a risky word spoken aloud. (PS: Calling it controversial is itself controversial, you realize. But down that road lies recursion.)

Comment: @tchrist I should have added a disclaimer of my Latin abilities: I have none. Also, I think controversy can be declaimed fairly objectively. If you disagree with someone over the controversial nature of something, then Q.E.D. it is controversial (or you've just created controversy, which is close to the same thing).

Comment: -1 The author is just looking for a single word, presumably he means an existing one that is documented somewhere and not one that you have made up.

Comment: @Frank A fair criticism. I thought it was a worthwhile discussion to have regarding *what* an honor-killing actually was, *how* its definition is already an oxymoron contrary to the definition of a typical word-concerning-human-induced-death, and *why* there isn't a single word. Anyways, I thought it was more interesting than just repeating "no, there isn't one." You covered that part well.

Comment: Sometimes _there isn't one_ kind of is the answer. I thought you'd covered the points well; you just hadn't come up with that magical 'single-word-request' answer. I should have down-voted 'honoricide' as well as it doesn't seem to be an established word (not even by urban dictionary standards).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a single word in this case. "Honor killing" and "revenge killing" are fairly common terms in English, though.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand there is no country in the world that considers an *honour killing* to be a legal act.

There are countries where it may be excused or used as a means for a shorter sentence or to avoid prosecution altogether but those countries still class it as an illegal act.

Therefore, the two most suitable single words in English for an *honour killing* are *homicide* or *murder*.

The definitions of the two terms are general reference.

Comment: Are you sure about the double negative in that first sentence?

Comment: @Rupe You might be right there (damn those double negatives and their double negativity) - edited

Comment: They rarely make it more difficult to parse a sentence incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

[MacMillain’s thesaurus entry for the oxymoronic term *honor-killing*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/The-crime-of-killing-and-ways-of-killing) suggests several terms for this sort of crime, including *murder*, *homicide*, and *manslaughter*.  Perhaps one of those may be to your liking.

On the other hand, depending on the relationship of the victim to her murderer, more specific terms for these horrible atrocities do exist:

- *matricide* – murdering one’s mother
- *uxoricide* — murdering one’s wife
- *filicide* — murdering one’s child
- *sororicide* — murdering one’s sister
- *nepoticide* — murdering one’s niece (or nephew)
- *parricide* — murdering one’s close relative
- *femicide* — murdering a woman
- *hereticide* — murdering a heretic

Those words do double duty as both the act itself and the victim.  So for example, one commits the crime of uxoricide when one murders one’s wife, and she, having been so slain, becomes an uxoricide herself.

As you can see, those all end in the *‑cide* suffix.  It is, alas, fairly productive, so although many such words derive directly from Latin, others are newly minted at need.  The OED says of this suffix (amongst other things):

> ### **-cide** /saɪd/, *suffix*.
>
> 1. a. F. *‑cide*, L. *‑cīda* cutter, killer, slayer, f. *cædĕre*, in comp. *‑cīdĕre* to cut, kill, as in *homicīda*, *parricīda*, *mātricīda*, *frātricīda*, *sorōricīda*, *tyrannicīda*, etc., slayer of a man, father, mother, brother, sister, tyrant, etc.; also *lapi*(*di*)*cīda*, stone-cutter, etc.
>
>    Most of the L. words having the sense ‘slayer, murderer’, have come down into Romanic and English, where new combinations have also been formed on the same type, notably *regicide* and *suicide*; *filicide* has also been used; and many occasional forms appear as jocose nonce-words, e.g. *apicide*, *avicide*, *canicide*, *ceticide*, *muricide*, *perdricide*, *tauricide*, *vaticide*, *verbicide*; or, still more ludicrously, *birdicide*, *prenticecide*, *suitorcide*, etc.
>
>    Also applied to preparations destructive of animal or vegetable life, as *algicide*, *fungicide*, *germicide*, *insecticide*, *pesticide*.
>
> [. . .]

If *hereticide* for murdering a heretic doesn’t quite fit, you could probably take the stem of *peccation* (meaning a ‘sin’) and make something like *peccaticide*, a word that I’ve so far found only in French texts.  To me it sounds more like *sin-killing* than *sinner-killing*, however.

If you don’t mind the sort of nonce-word words which the OED calls jocose and possibly even ludicrous, perhaps *sinnercide* would convey the meaning you intend.  It’s no sillier than *guilty-killing*.

Comment: -1 for manslaughter. Accidental honour killing, oxymoronic or just ?

Comment: Manslaughter is a death caused by another human that doesn't amount to murder due to the circumstance of the crime; manslaughter does not have to be accidental. Recognized causes for reducing a charge manslaughter include the lack of motive and intention (e.g. vehicular manslaughter of a pedestrian), lack of malice aforethought (e.g. crime of passion, or defending oneself or one's family with too much force), or other mitigating legal factors. If the judicial system in question recognizes honor as a legal factor, manslaughter *could* be a charge levied for an honor-killing.

Comment: @Frank Please see the comment immediately below yours; you may well wish to reconsider.

Comment: Note that I would not want to live under (or even pass through) such a judicial system; cultural traditions aside. Honor is *way* too subjective for a legal precedent (and that's an understatement). In other words, I'm glad manslaughter doesn't mean  honor-killing in English. However, it is a reasonable translation from a language/culture that does recognize such legal factors. (PS I would upvote, but I already did.) (PPS Feel free to incorporate this point into your answer.)

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, but no.