# A word for killing a cousin

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Almost every type of killing can be described in a single word such as suicide, parricide, genocide, etc.

Is there such a term for killing a cousin specifically?

Comment: It's usually a regrettable state of affairs when one goes from *kissing cousins* to *killing cousins*.

Comment: Kinslaying! [cit.]

Comment: My comment is that if you are going to **coin** a word for this then ***cousinicide*** has the clearest (transparent) meaning (though it, like other suggestions here, is ugly).  If the point is to communicate in English, then it is the modern meaning of *cousin* that you want to work with, not various shades of cousin relations that were more pertinent in the past or are more pertinent now in non-English settings. Which is more important to you: coining from Latin or Greek roots or coming up with a word that clearly means what it says?

Answer (score 8):

To my knowledge, there is no such accepted term. As Josh points out, *parricide* can be used to refer to any close relationship, though the main sense is that of killing a parent (i.e., *patricide* and/or *matricide*).

For lack of an accepted, specific term, you could use one of two fairly rare, but etymologically sound, neologisms that have been coined:

> ***(con)sobrinicide***
>   Killing your maternal cousin
>
> ***patruelicide***
>   Killing your paternal cousin

These are derived from Latin *(con)sobrīnus* ‘mother’s sister’s child’ and *patruelis* ‘father’s brother’s child’. To anyone with decent Latin skills, they should be self-explanatory and obvious, though they probably won’t be to others; and no dictionary that I could find has included the words (yet).

Comment: I don’t see why not. The *‑cide* element is [reasonably productive](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/184607/) — well, or maybe unreasonably so, depending on one’s point  of view.

Answer (score 1):

I think [parricide](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Parricide) is the correct term to use in your case:

> - The murdering of one's father, mother, or other near relative.
> - One who commits such a murder.

Source: [Killing one's relations](http://www.fun-with-words.com/cide_words.html):

Source:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_killing

Comment: Possibly usable in the situation, but does not describe the killing of a _cousin_ in particular.

Comment: I think that's the term to use that best describes that kind of killing. See the lists I included.

Answer (score 1):

@Josh61 gives a good answer using existing terms, but it shouldn't be too difficult to coin a more specific term - or is it?

All these killing words are hybrid constructions, combining the *-cide* suffix (which can be [traced back](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=-cide&allowed_in_frame=0) to Latin *cida* "cutter, killer, slayer") with a first element that is *usually* derived from Latin or Greek. So all you need to do is find a good Latin or Greek work for *cousin* and append the suffix, right? You can even use a non-Greek or Latin base, since the existing terms already mix up Latin and Greek (*sui* is Latin, *geno* is Greek) and give language purists the hives.

The only problem is that in most classical languages, there wasn't a single, encompassing word for cousins. Latin has several terms like *cognatus*, which can be used for more general kinsmen. Or maybe *sobrinus* for maternal cousins, or *patruelis* on the father's side. Other languages also have [many different words](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=cousin&allowed_in_frame=0) for specific relationships:

> Many IE languages (including Irish, Sanskrit, Slavic, and some of the Germanic tongues) have or had separate words for some or all of the eight possible "cousin" relationships, such as Latin, which along with consobrinus had consobrina "mother's sister's daughter," patruelis "father's brother's son," matruelis "mother's brother's son," amitinus "father's sister's son," etc. Old English distinguished fæderan sunu "father's brother's son," modrigan sunu "mother's sister's son," etc.

So choosing the exact term to base your *-cide* on might be difficult. If you have a very specific killing-word in mind, you could use a specific Latin term. Or, perhaps, just stick to Josh61's more general *parricide*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was looking at the putative **atruelis* and thinking about what the word for killing off the black sheep of the family would be. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go with *sobrinicide* although (a) technically that would only refer to a cousin on your mother's side (*patruelicide* would be a paternal cousin) and (b) no one would know what you are talking about.

Still, somebody has to coin new words, might as well be you.

**Edit**: while I was typing this, Avner Shahar-Kashtan made the virtually identical recommendation.  Therefore, I am now suggesting you go the Greek route and use *exodelphicide*.

Comment: Actually, I made the virtually identical recommendation, not Avner. :-)

Comment: That'd be _ex*a*delphicide_.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the latin for cousin, according to google translate, is cognata, so killing one's cousin could be "cognaticide" or "cognatacide"

Comment: Google translate is not suitable for looking up individual words; if you consulted a Latin-English dictionary you would notice that this is wrong: http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/cognata